# Demonstrate that $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}] \simeq \mathbb{C}^{6}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is a review problem that I'm solving. I have been told that
$ \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}] $ is a $ \mathbb{C} $ algebra so a vector space where the field is $\mathbb{C}$ and the 'vectors' are $[\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}]$. I'm quite confused as to what the 'action' is in this case, since $[i]_{2}$ does not make any sense, so I'm assuming its kind of like a group ring where you simply have $i(0,1)$ where $(0,1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. So really, this question is asking me to demonstrate a ring isomorphism between these two algebraic objects. So we define a map, $\phi:\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{6}$ where,
$$\phi(0,0) = (0,0,0,0,0,0), \phi(0,1) = (1,0,0,0,0,0), \phi(0,2) = (0,1,0,0,0,0), $$
but this idea does not work because $\phi(0,2) + \phi(0,1) \ne \phi(0,0)$. I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{6}$, but I still don't know how to 'encode' the vectors into $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you not have maschke's theorem at hand?

Comment: There is one homomorphism to $\Bbb{C}$ per character of your abelian group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're allowed to use Maschke's theorem or not, but let's look at solutions that involve that.

Basically, if $G$ is an abelian group of order $n$, then $\mathbb C[G]$ is a commutative semisimple $\mathbb C$ algebra, so it has to be copies of $\mathbb C$, and we know there will be $n$ of them.  From that you could conclude that $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3]\cong \mathbb C^6$ since the group has order $6$.

Actually, you can work out that $\mathbb C[G\times H]\cong\mathbb C[G]\otimes_\mathbb C\mathbb C[H]$.  For similar reasons the pieces of the product have dimension $2$ and $3$, and so the dimension of their tensor product will be $6$ in total.  Using this latter piece you can see how the two smaller groups are 'encoded' into the larger one, and their group rings are encoded into the full group ring.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $G$ is a group, the [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) $R[G]$ is an $R$-algebra, together with a map $i_G \colon G \to R[G]$, characterized by the following *universal property*:

> For any $R$-algebra $S$, every group homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $S^\times$ (the group of units of $S$) can be uniquely ‘extended’ to an $R$-algebra homomorphism $R[G] \to S$; that is, there exists a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $\bar f \colon R[G] \to S$ such that $f \circ i_G$ is the same as $f$ followed by $S^\times \hookrightarrow S$.

Any other $R$-algebra $A$ with a map $G \to A$ satisfying the above property is isomorphic to $R[G]$.

---

So, what we need to do here is, first, give a map $i \colon \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 \to \Bbb C^6$; and then prove that if $S$ is a $\Bbb C$-algebra and $f \colon \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 \to S^\times$ a group homomorphism, then there exists a unique $\Bbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\bar f \colon \Bbb C^6 \to S$ such that $f \circ i$ is $f$ followed by $S^\times \hookrightarrow S$. (Hint: Try to define $i$ so that its image is the canonical basis for $\Bbb C^6$.)